# Replace < and > using &lt; and &gt;

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a text input and a div that contains the same text. I'm using the below line to make line breaks in the DIV text same as in the input text.

```
$('#tF').html( $(this).val().replace(/\n/g, '<br />') );
```

Question: How do I write the `'<br />` by using `&lt;` and `&gt;`?

Example (does not work):

```
$('#tF').html( $(this).val().replace(/[<>]/g, function(_){ return {'<':'&lt;','>':'&gt;'}[_]; }).replace(/\n/g, '<br />' );
```

Comment: What for do you need it?

Comment: try `text($(this).val().replace(/\n/g, '<br />'))` instead of `html($(this).val()....)`

Comment: @ForceBru Thanks. Because the output will be shown as HTML, and may break everything if someone introduces bad html such as a `<a` in the textarea

Comment: @marcel Thanks. that won't work coz of the `<br>` will be in shown as a string instead of a linebreak.

Comment: maybe this: `$(this).val().split('<').join('&lt;').split('>').join('&gt;').replace(/\n/g, '<br />' )`

Comment: @marcel That suggestion does not server the purpose I guess?

Comment: @Becky if [this](https://jsfiddle.net/marcelortega/m4hk2hbs/2/) is not what you meant, pls show me the expected output.

Comment: @marcel: Thanks, appreciate that. Here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mrk0cx3g/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this small function I found in a previous post

```
function escapeHtml(text) {
  var map = {
    '&': '&amp;',
    '<': '&lt;',
    '>': '&gt;',
    '"': '&quot;',
    "'": '&#039;'
  };

  return text.replace(/[&<>"']/g, function(m) { return map[m]; });
}
```

And then

```
$('#tF').html( escapeHtml( $(this).val() ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to accomplish this the way you are asking, but you could split up the text at every line break and use `.append($("<br />"))` in between chunks.

Answer (score 0):

You can pull those replace `&lt` and `&gt` apart like:

```
$('#tF').html($(this).val().replace(/\n/g, '<br />').replace(/</g, '$lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;'));
```